# How do I use the same layout for every page, but vary the Content component via the URL route in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, layout

I'm using Typescript and Next.js

I want to have a single `<Layout>` for all my pages.  In the layout, I have `<Header>`, `<Footer>`, `<Sidenav>`, and `<Content>` components. It looks like this:

```
interface LayoutProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

const Layout = ({ children }: LayoutProps) => {
  return (
    <Grid templateAreas={`"header header"
                          "side content"
                          "footer footer"`}
      gridTemplateColumns={'250px 1fr'}>
      <GridItem area={'header'}> <Header /></GridItem>
      <GridItem area={'content'}> <Content>{children}</Content> </GridItem>
      <GridItem area={'side'}><SimpleSidebar /> </GridItem>
      <GridItem area={'footer'}><Footer /> </GridItem>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

My `index.tsx` file is as follows:

```
const Page: NextPageWithLayout = () => {
  return <p>hello world</p>
}

Page.getLayout = function getLayout(page: ReactElement) {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider>
      <Layout>
        { page }
      </Layout>
    </ChakraProvider>
  )
}

export default Page
```

I am trying to vary the content based on the URL so that the  component is filled with my About Page info when the URL is https://example.com/about

My `_app.tsx` looks like this:

```
export type NextPageWithLayout<P = {}, IP = P> = NextPage<P, IP> & {
  getLayout?: (page: ReactElement) => ReactNode
}

type AppPropsWithLayout = AppProps & {
  Component: NextPageWithLayout
}

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppPropsWithLayout) {
  // Use the layout defined at the page level, if available
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout ?? ((page) => page)

  return getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)
}
```

I cannot for the life of me find anything on Google about how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code runs just fine in [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/youthful-browser-sqipsh?file=%2Fpages%2Fabout.tsx&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A37%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A10%2C%22startColumn%22%3A37%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A10%7D%5D).

If what you're looking for is for `Layout` to be rendered on **every** page, you shouldn't be using this `getLayout` pattern but instead just rendering it around the `Component` in `_app.tsx`.

Comment: Thanks very much. I was indeed "over-controlling it," as they say.